# Uncaught ReferenceError: Oncheckboxclicked is not defined at HTMLElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Hi i am trying to create two radio button which when clicked will display either a button to upload a file or a link to upload . but after adding radio button and making `onclick` function it still doesn't work

```
<app-side-bar *ngIf="authService.isAuth"></app-side-bar>
<app-header-static></app-header-static>
<div class="web-container" [style.center]="!authService.isAuth">
  <div class="challenge-create-flex">
    <div class="challenge-create-content">
      <section class="ev-md-container text-center ">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col s12 m9 offset-m3">
              <label id="choose_meth">Please upload zip file or provide the link to it  to create a challenge!</label>
              <mat-radio-group class="smallradio" aria-labelledby="choose_meth">
                <mat-radio-button name="upload_challange" value="2" onclick="Oncheckboxclicked(value)">Upload File</mat-radio-button>
                <mat-radio-button name="upload_challange" value="5" onclick="Oncheckboxclicked(value)">Provide Link</mat-radio-button>
              </mat-radio-group>
            <div class="file-field input-field col s6">
              <form name="ChallengeCreateForm" #ChallengeCreateForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="challengeCreate()" novalidate>
                <div class="waves-effect waves-dark btn ev-btn-dark w-300 fs-14" id="upload_file" >
                  <span>Upload File</span>
                  <input name="input_file" (change)="handleUpload($event)"  accept=".json, .zip, .txt" type="file" class="text-dark-black dark-autofill w-400" [(ngModel)]="ChallengeCreateForm['input_file']">
                </div>

                <div class="file-path-wrapper" id="prov_url" >
                  <input  class="file-path validate" name="file_path" type="url">
                  <div *ngIf="isFormError" class="wrn-msg text-highlight fs-12"> Please Upload File </div>
                </div> 

                <div class="align-left reg-control" id="Submitbutton">
                  <button class="btn ev-btn-dark waves-effect waves-dark grad-btn grad-btn-dark fs-14" type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
                </div>

              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col s12 m9 offset-m3">
            <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
            To know how to create a challenge using zip file configuration, please see our documentation
            <a href="https://evalai.readthedocs.io/en/latest/challenge_creation.html#challenge-creation-using-zip-configuration" class="highlight-link" target="_blank">here.</a>.
          </div>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="isSyntaxErrorInYamlFile" class="row">
          <hr class="hr-line">
          <div class="col s12 m9 offset-m3">
            <div class="syntax-wrn-msg text-highlight">
              The YAML file in the challenge configuration contains the following error - <br>
              {{syntaxErrorInYamlFile}}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

    </div>
    <app-footer [isDash]="true" *ngIf="authService.isAuth"></app-footer>
  </div>
</div>

<app-footer *ngIf="!authService.isAuth"></app-footer>
```

and below is typescript

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChildren, QueryList, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { ApiService } from '../../services/api.service';
import { GlobalService } from '../../services/global.service';
import { ChallengeService } from '../../services/challenge.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import {DOCUMENT} from '@angular/common';

/**
 * Component Class
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'app-challenge-create',
  templateUrl: './challenge-create.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./challenge-create.component.scss']
})
export class ChallengeCreateComponent implements OnInit {

  isFormError = false;
  isSyntaxErrorInYamlFile = false;
  ChallengeCreateForm = {
    input_file: null,
    file_path: null
  };
  syntaxErrorInYamlFile = {};

  /**
   * Auth Service public instance
   */
  authServicePublic = null;

  /**
   * Is user logged in
   */
  isLoggedIn = false;

  /**
   * Router public instance
   */
  routerPublic = null;

  /**
   * Selected Host team object
   */
  hostTeam: any = null;

  /**
   * Route for hosted challenges
   */
  hostedChallengesRoute = '/challenges/me';

  /**
   * Route path for host teams
   */
  hostTeamsRoute = '/teams/hosts';

  /**
   * Constructor.
   * @param route  ActivatedRoute Injection.
   * @param router  Router Injection.
   * @param authService  AuthService Injection.
   * @param document
   * @param globalService  GlobalService Injection.
   * @param apiService  ApiService Injection.
   * @param challengeService  ChallengeService Injection.
   */
  constructor(public authService: AuthService, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private challengeService: ChallengeService, @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document,
              private globalService: GlobalService, private apiService: ApiService) { }

  /**
   * Component on initialized.
   */
  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
      this.isLoggedIn = true;
    }
    this.authServicePublic = this.authService;
    this.routerPublic = this.router;
    this.challengeService.currentHostTeam.subscribe((hostTeam) => {
      this.hostTeam = hostTeam;
      if (!hostTeam) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.globalService.showToast('info', 'Please select a host team');
        }, 1000);
        this.router.navigate([this.hostTeamsRoute]);
      }
    });
  }


  challengeCreate() {
    if (this.ChallengeCreateForm['input_file'] !== null) {
      const FORM_DATA: FormData = new FormData();
      FORM_DATA.append('status', 'submitting');
      FORM_DATA.append('zip_configuration', this.ChallengeCreateForm['input_file']);
      this.globalService.startLoader('Creating Challenge');
      this.challengeService.challengeCreate(
        this.hostTeam['id'],
        FORM_DATA,
      ).subscribe(
        data => {
          this.globalService.stopLoader();
          this.globalService.showToast('success', 'Successfuly sent to EvalAI admin for approval.');
          this.router.navigate([this.hostedChallengesRoute]);
        },
        err => {
          this.globalService.stopLoader();
          this.globalService.showToast('error', err.error.error);
          this.isSyntaxErrorInYamlFile = true;
          this.syntaxErrorInYamlFile = err.error.error;
        },
        () => {}
        );
    } else {
      this.isFormError = true;
      this.globalService.showToast('error', 'Please Upload File');
    }
  }

  handleUpload(event) {
    const files = event.target.files;

    if (files.length >= 1) {
      this.isFormError = false;
      this.ChallengeCreateForm['input_file'] = event.target.files[0];
      this.ChallengeCreateForm['file_path'] = event.target.files[0]['name'];
      this.document.getElementsByClassName('file-path')[0].value = event.target.files[0]['name'];
    } else {
      this.isFormError = true;
    }
  }
   Oncheckboxclicked(value: any){
    if (value == 2 ) {
      var urlfield =<HTMLElement>this.document.getElementById("prov_url");
     var buttonshow =<HTMLElement>this.document.getElementById("SubmitButton");
     urlfield.style.display = 'block';
     buttonshow.style.display = 'block';
    }if (value == 5) {
      var filebutton = <HTMLElement>this.document.getElementById("upload_file");;
      var buttonshow =<HTMLElement>this.document.getElementById("SubmitButton");
      filebutton.style.display = 'block';
     buttonshow.style.display = 'block';

    }
    return null;
  }

}
```

Th error is

> uncaught ReferenceError: Oncheckboxclicked is not defined
>       at HTMLElement.onclick

Comment: sir what is wrong with my code?

Comment: it was just an advice, i thought you are learning angular without learning core javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `(change)` event. Use it like bellow.

```
<mat-radio-button name="upload_challange" value="2" (change)="Oncheckboxclicked(value)">Upload File</mat-radio-button>
<mat-radio-button name="upload_challange" value="5" (change)="Oncheckboxclicked(value)">Provide Link</mat-radio-button>
```

> Event emitted when the checked state of this radio button changes.
>   Change events are only emitted when the value changes due to user
>   interaction with the radio button (the same behavior as ).

Refer their [DOC for more details](https://material.angular.io/components/radio/api)

Comment: i  have tried it previously the error didn't show up but neither the result so how can i check if the function i even being called??

Comment: use like `(change)="Oncheckboxclicked($event)"` and in component `Oncheckboxclicked(event: MdRadioChange)` and read value by using like  `event.value`

Comment: yes it did but now my code is throwing this error : ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Comment: your view has id like `Submitbutton` `<div class="align-left reg-control" id="Submitbutton">` but you try get it like `this.document.getElementById("SubmitButton");` please use here like `this.document.getElementById("Submitbutton")`

Comment: if this post helps you to solve the original issue, could you please accept (tick) this as  a correct answer